# margin not working when i convert html to pdf on button click

Tags: html, css, pdf-generation

I want to space between **durgesh**  and **last** word so, I use this CSS:-

**"margin-left: 20px"**

it is proper working on the browser but when I  generate pdf through **generate pdf** button

*CSS property is not working*

**please open js fiddle link in new window because *"generate PDF"* button is not working StackOverflow**

```html
<script async src="//jsfiddle.net/5ud8jkvf/9475/embed/"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `media="print"` for it.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="print" href="mystyle.css">

@media print {
  /* css code goes here */
}
```

`<style type="text/css"> @media print { } </style>` or you can use `<style media="print"></style>`

Comment: but i am using inline css

Comment: Then you have to make  margin properties classes and put them in media="print"

Comment: it is not working please help !

@media print {
  .space{
margin-left: 20px;
}                

HTML
<p><b>Name:</b>durgesh<b class="space">last:</b>Dangi</p>

Comment: @media print { .space { margin-left: 20px; } } you can use  <style type="text/css" media="print" ></style>

Comment: @media print {
  .space{
margin-left: 20px;
}

}

thanks for help but it is not working

Comment: we want to export a invoice and first name and last name are mix when print

Comment: you can use  <style type="text/css">  @media print { } </style> or you can use <style media="print"></style>

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144332/discussion-between-durgesh-dangi-and-lokesh-gupta).